# How to add Font Awesome in Vue.js

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm trying to use Font Awesome with Vue 3. I have made a separate file for font awesome Icons here, but not sure if this is the correct way to add icons in Vue.

main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";

createApp(App).component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon).mount('#app')
```

fontawesome-icons.js file:

```
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { faUndo } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";

library.add(faUndo);

export default FontAwesomeIcon;
```

Task.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'Undo']" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Follow this guide.
https://blog.fontawesome.com/how-to-use-vue-js-with-font-awesome/

Comment: @SaudQureshi My icons are rendering perfectly well by following this approach but I want my icons to be in a separate file. Can you please check again and see if there is anything I'm missing.

Comment: @SaudQureshi Never mind, I figured out from here https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/how-to-use-fon-awesome-5-on-vuejs-project-ff0f28310821